# How to arrange data in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In crystal report's **Field Explorer (left side)** shown below, I have two tables, and I want two tables to be shown differently. I.e., I want `Patient ID` and `PFirst` name shown together and below that I want to show Images column separately.

Now If I shift Images column below `PatientID` than data gets overlapped, How I can Display two tables separately? 
[image: Crystalreport.rpt file view]
**See Like this Data is getting overlapped shown in below image**
[image: Overlapping Data View]

Comment: Is there any relationship between Datatable1 and Datatable2?

Comment: @PratikKaje No right now their is no relationship between two tables

Comment: If you could add some unique relationship between two tables then you can create a subreport and add image in it. I think even if there is no relationship then also it should work.

Comment: @PratikKaje u mean now I should use sub report ? ,but can't I do this without sub report ?

Comment: No, then it will overlap. If you don't want to add sub report then see if you could add Images column in your table datatable1 and use only that table for output.

Comment: @PratikKaje No I want Images Column Separately only ,dn I need to use subreport only

Comment: Please upvote if you are satisfied with the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Right Click On Crystal report design -> Insert-> SubReport`

After this `Add table` to be shown and its `Fields` Using this Data will be shown Properly and will not overllap

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another section below details (details b) and place images there and run the report.

Comment: `Right Click` on details and click `Insert section below` option.

Comment: Go to section expert of the `Details a` section and `uncheck` option `Underlay Following Sections` and check the report

Comment: what exactly is happening there? which data is getting overlapped? image or name?

Comment: Please leave your messager here I can't join the chat

Comment: To be specific I don't see any overlap there only thing I understood here is your placement of data is wrong in the report. Give sufficeint space between Detail a and detail b and place the patien ID and patient name exaclty above the image. I can see the report is fine only thing is your placement is not fine.

Comment: I am fetching only one row ,but that row is displayed in report repeatedly,and Images column is overlapped on PatientId column

Comment: I can provide you one last solution it this doesn't work I apologize unable to slove your issue. Create one more section after datails b, Create details c and then run the report.